# Get Innertext from an XML string which has only one node without looping

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML string which looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><Product><ID>0701161476416</ID><UNIQUE_ID>test26051602</UNIQUE_ID><STATUS>DONE</STATUS></Product>
```

It is know that my XML string will always has a single node ans so I do not want to look, instead I would like to get Unique_ID and Status inner values without looping.

May I know a better way to do it and I do have the below code which actually loops through each node

```
                            XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                            xm.LoadXml(XML_STRING);

                            XmlNodeList xnList = xm.SelectNodes("/Product/Product");
                            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                            {
                                string uniqueID = xn["UNIQUE_ID"].InnerText;
                                string status = xn["STATUS"].InnerText;                               
                            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can use for this purpose :

```
XmlNode product = xm.SelectSingleNode("/Product/Product");
string uniqueID = product["UNIQUE_ID"].InnerText;
string status = product["STATUS"].InnerText;
```

Or, if `Product` is the root element, then you can access it from [`DocumentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `XmlDocument` :

```
XmlNode product = xm.DocumentElement;
string uniqueID = product["UNIQUE_ID"].InnerText;
string status = product["STATUS"].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one product try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"Windows-1252\"?>" +
                "<Products>" +
                  "<Product>" +
                    "<ID>0701161476416</ID>" +
                    "<UNIQUE_ID>test26051603</UNIQUE_ID>" +
                    "<STATUS>DONE</STATUS>" +
                  "</Product>" +
                  "<Product>" +
                    "<ID>0701161476417</ID>" +
                    "<UNIQUE_ID>test26051604</UNIQUE_ID>" +
                    "<STATUS>DONE</STATUS>" +
                  "</Product>" +
                  "<Product>" +
                    "<ID>0701161476418</ID>" +
                    "<UNIQUE_ID>test26051605</UNIQUE_ID>" +
                    "<STATUS>DONE</STATUS>" +
                  "</Product>" +
                "</Products>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Product").Select(x => new
            {
                id = (long)x.Element("ID"),
                uniqueID = (string)x.Element("UNIQUE_ID"),
                status = (string)x.Element("STATUS")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work, but I guess there is a better solution:

```
XDocument xm = XDocument.Parse(XML_STRING);
var product = xm.Element("Product").Element("Product");
string uniqueID = product.Element("UNIQUE_ID").Value;
string status = product.Element("STATUS").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SelectNodes line seemed wrong for the sample Xml.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xm.SelectNodes("/Product");
if (xnList.Count > 0)
{
  string uniqueID = xnList[0]["UNIQUE_ID"].InnerText;
  string status = xnList[0]["STATUS"].InnerText;
}
```